# Modal images have troubles with classes

Tags: javascript, html

I got this modal script to display bigger images on my site. It worked well, but only with 1 image. When i tried to add more images - script didn't worked, and nothing was happening. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Here's some code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("zdjecie");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<img class="zdjecie" style="max-height: 16rem;max-width: 16rem;" src="example.jpg">
```

When I was using ID's instead of classes it worked well - but i couldn't add more images - that's why i need to use classes. Someone has any ideas? I'd be greatful

Comment: img.onclick doesn't work, because it is an array.

Comment: Did you delete your previous question? Since you had answers there before. Just as you show here: `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];`, if you use `var img = document.getElementsByClassName("zdjecie");`, you have to use `img[0]` to select the first image, `img[1]` for the second image.

Comment: No i didn't deleted any question as af as i can remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array, which contains all the dom has the `zdjecie` class.

So you have to loop through this array to add the event, or put these images inside a container and use `event-delegation`, which is a more efficient way. Because it just bind event once. More about `event-delegation`: https://javascript.info/event-delegation`

Here is the code using  `event-delegation`.

```js
var handleImageClick =  function(evt){
  if(evt.target.className.indexOf('zdjecie') === -1) return;
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = evt.target.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = evt.target.alt;
 
}
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
imageContainer.addEventListener('click', handleImageClick)

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.zdjecie{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
    <img class="zdjecie" alt="1"  style="max-height: 16rem;max-width: 16rem;" src="example1.jpg" />
    <img class="zdjecie" alt="2"  style="max-height: 16rem;max-width: 16rem;" src="example2.jpg" />
    <img class="zdjecie" alt="3" style="max-height: 16rem;max-width: 16rem;" src="example3.jpg" />
    <img class="zdjecie"  alt="4" style="max-height: 16rem;max-width: 16rem;" src="example4.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="myModal">
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <img id="img01" style="max-height: 16rem;max-width: 16rem;" />
  <p id="caption"></p>
</div>
```